# How to sort multidimensional array in ascending form?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is the array. What I want is I wanna sort the array on the basis on 'income_difference' in ascending order. If possible, I just want 3 data with least income difference.

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "month" => "11"
    "income_times" => 2
    "income_amount" => 52300
    "income_difference" => 49000
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "month" => "10"
    "income_times" => 1
    "income_amount" => 50000
    "income_difference" => 46700
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "month" => "09"
    "income_times" => 1
    "income_amount" => 5000000
    "income_difference" => 4996700
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "month" => "08"
    "income_times" => 1
    "income_amount" => 50000
    "income_difference" => 46700
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "month" => "06"
    "income_times" => 1
    "income_amount" => 5200
    "income_difference" => 1900
  ]
]
```

Comment: you can do manual bubble sort according to `month` param https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: did you try any thing before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use usort:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['income_difference'] - $b['income_difference'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to maintain the index(0,1,2,3) you can use `usort`
e.g

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['income_difference'] == $b['income_difference']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['income_difference'] < $b['income_difference']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($yourArray,'cmp')
```

If you want to maintain the index (0,1,2,3) you can use `uasort` instead of `usort`. Other syntax remains the same.

For more details on functionality please refer [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)